# Stepwise logistic regression: What exactly is meant by eliminating features based on contribution?

Tags: r, logistic, stepwise-regression

I would like to know how my program is selecting and removing features during stepwise regression.

I'm using R's caret package which in turn I think is using stepAIC from the MASS package.

I was reading the MASS documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/MASS.pdf) (pdf).

However, I could not find any reference to what criteria are used during each iteration of adding or subtracting  a feature.

I recall reading a paragraph of text, I think within the well known ISLR book that stepwise regression optimizes to p-values/feature significance on step backwards regression, RSS on stepforwards, and then both during mixed. Don't quote me on that though.

Does the direction/method determine which criteria are used to pick features (pvalue significance, RSS, both)?

Is it some combination of the above 3 criteria that are used?

Comment: The function at every step adds (or removes) every variable (that is still being considered) and looks at the change in AIC. It then selects the one variable that increases the AIC the most.